# Sprite changed on specific value - can't figure out how calculate the value

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

thanks for any help,

I have a function where sprite is change when AngelsValue or DevilsValue change.

what I'm trying to do is :

IF AngelsValue is 3 times MORE than DevilsValue = sprite change

IF AngelsValue is 5 times MORE than DevilsValue = sprite change

IF AngelsValue is 7 times MORE than DevilsValue = sprite change

and other way around

IF DevilsValue is 3 times MORE than AngelsValue = sprite change

IF DevilsValue is 5 times MORE than AngelsValue = sprite change

IF DevilsValue is 7 times MORE than AngelsValue = sprite change

my code work but for ONLY specific number... and to put that in life to value of example 100.. I would have 100 Lines of code :)

thanks a lot.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerSpriteChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite AngelStage2;

    public Sprite AngelStage3;

    public Sprite AngelStage4;

    public Sprite DevilStage2;

    public Sprite DevilStage3;

    public Sprite DevilStage4;

    void Update()
    {


        if (AngelsCount.AngelsValue >=3 && DevilsCOunt.DevilsValue <= 1)

        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = AngelStage2;


        }

        else if (AngelsCount.AngelsValue >= 5 && DevilsCOunt.DevilsValue <= 3)
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = AngelStage3;
        }

        else if (AngelsCount.AngelsValue >= 7 && DevilsCOunt.DevilsValue <= 5)
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = AngelStage4;
        }



        else if (DevilsCOunt.DevilsValue >= 3 && AngelsCount.AngelsValue <= 1)
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = DevilStage2;
        }

        else if (DevilsCOunt.DevilsValue >= 5 && AngelsCount.AngelsValue <= 3)
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = DevilStage3;
        }

        else if (DevilsCOunt.DevilsValue >= 7 && AngelsCount.AngelsValue <= 5)
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = DevilStage4;
        }










    }
}
```

Comment: you can put your code into for loop

Comment: Your code: `if (AngelsCount.AngelsValue >=3)` Computer: "Yes, 7 is definitely bigger than 3. Well then I guess I do this bit: `sprite = AngelStage2` and I'm done, because all of those other statements only happen if this first bit was false.

Answer (score 2):

Are they always going to be 2 apart numerically?  If so you can just use a for loop.  If you take i subtract 3 and divide by 2 you can also have a continuous 0-based sequence to easily grab your sprites.  Starting with 3 = (3 - 3)/2 = 0,  5 = (5 - 3)/2 = 1.  7 = (7 - 3)/2 = 2, etc.  And then just do the same thing just opposite for devils.

```
for (int i = 3; i <= 7; i += 2)
{
   if ((AngelsCount.AngelValue / DevilsCount.DevilsValue) >= i)
   {
      this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = GetAngelStage((i - 3)/2);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but no they can be far away a part, one can be 20 other 60.. but I need to "detect" when they are 2 or 3 apart from each other.. and like i wrote m code kind of work but I would need a lot of lines to do it.

Comment: Unless you determine a predictable interval then you will need to code each line.